# DNS Error : extra input text

Tags: dns, centos-7, bind

I am configuring my private DNS server.  When I reached the Check BIND Configuration Syntax step, I got some errors.

Here is the my Forward Zone File :

```
$ORIGIN esprit1.com.
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     ns.esprit1.com. root.esprit1.com. (
        4      ; serial
        3600            ; refresh after 2 hours
        3600            ; retry after 1 hour
        604800          ; expire after 1 week
        86400 )         ; minimum TTL of 1 day
;
; Primary nameserver
        IN      NS      ns.esprit1.com.
;
; Define A records (forward lookups)
@ IN NS ns.esprit1.com. 
@ IN A 192.168.147.138  
ns IN A 192.168.147.138 
web1 IN A  192.168.147.138
mail IN A  192.168.147.138
```

Here is the my Reverse Zone File :

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ns.esprit1.com. root.ns.esprit1.com.(
4
10800
3600
3600
604800
86400 )
@ IN NS ns.esprit1.com.
138 IN PTR ns.esprit1.com.
138 PTR web1.esprit1.com
138 PTR mail.esprit1.com
```

And when i run the command for the Reverse file `named-checkzone esprit1.com /var/named/147.168.192.db` it gives me this :

```
[root@localhost named]# named-checkzone esprit1.com /var/named/147.168.192.db
dns_rdata_fromtext: /var/named/147.168.192.db:7: near '86400': extra input text
zone esprit1.com/IN: loading from master file /var/named/147.168.192.db failed: extra input text
zone esprit1.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Comment: It's a bit of a guess, but could it be there should be a space between com. and ( on line 2 of your reverse zone file ? so "root.ns.esprit1.com.(" becomes "root.ns.esprit1.com. ("

Answer (score 1):

SOA's have 5 entries; serial, refresh, retry, expire & minimum.

Your rDNS file has 6 entries. I assume 10800 is the odd one out.

Comment: when i delete the line of 10800 it shows this error : 

zone esprit1.com/IN: NS 'ns.esprit1.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)'

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved The problem was in the command for the Reverse file `named-checkzone esprit1.com /var/named/147.168.192.db`
The right command is `named-checkzone 147.168.192 /var/named/147.168.192.db`